# Activation of pre-release builds via terminal or Configuring Testflight to automatically activate new builds for testing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Is there a way to activate pre-release builds (activating them for beta testing) without having to go to iTunes Connect's dashboard and manually activating them?

Every time I have a new build I have to go there, click on the app, click on pre-release and click the toggle. Being able to do it via terminal would fix my problem.

The old testflight didn't had this, i.e. builds were available right after you uploaded them.

Edit: I was expecting a solution that wouldn't require third party tools. However it seems like using fastlane is indeed the best solution. I may mark that answer correct, but I need to try that out first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fantastic [deliver](https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver) tool. It supports both uploading a new build and activating it for pre-release testing (aka Apple TestFlight beta testing).

Comment: Just a P.S.: and you can use Deliver with our Continuous Integration service to do it completely automatically for you ;) - https://bitrise.io/ - CTO here

Answer (score 1):

My company was using the old Testflight service for adhoc/beta builds running on a Jenkins server. When it finally stopped working, I looked into using the new Testflight service and was pretty bummed to see that (at least at the time) there was no way to set up automation with it, so we stopped using it. We have now switched over to using [Crashlytics Beta](http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/) which accomplishes pretty much 100% what the old Testflight did with full commandline (and hence automation) support. It also comes with some other nice features.